# Anytime strongly connected components via Prolog

Tags: prolog, strongly-connected-graph, prolog-tabling

Markus Triska has reported an algorithm to determine [strongly connected components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34833797/502187) (SCC). Is there a solution which determines the SCC without making use of attributed variable and that can work anytime. So that some vertices can have infinitely many edges?

I am asking because I am wondering whether B-Prologs [anytime tabling](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3468) which they call eager can be replicated. B-Prolog determines clusters which is their name for SCC. But it has also a tabling mode where it returns tabled results eagerly.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this [algorithm](https://gist.github.com/jburse/aae8612011182f10683dd079b2e1d1b0#gistcomment-3066749) fits the bill, since with a little modification it would allow an infinite degree in the root. This is the SCC algorithm when all edges point to finitely many vertices:

```
% plan(+Atom, -Assoc)
plan(P, R) :-
  sccforpred(P, [], [], R, _).

% sccforpred(+Atom, +List, +Assoc, -Assoc, -List)
sccforpred(P, S, H, H, [P]) :-
  member(P, S), !.
sccforpred(P, _, H, H, []) :-
  member(Q-L, H), (Q = P; member(P, L)), !.
sccforpred(P, S, I, O2, R2) :-
  findall(Q, edge(P, Q), L),
  sccforlist(L, [P|S], I, O, R),
  (member(U, R), member(U, S) ->
      O2 = O, R2 = [P|R];
      O2 = [P-R|O], R2 = []).

% sccforlist(+List, +List, +Assoc, -Assoc, -List)
sccforlist([], _, H, H, []).
sccforlist([P|Q], S, I, O, R) :-
  sccforpred(P, S, I, H, R1),
  sccforlist(Q, S, H, O, R2),
  findall(U, (member(U, R1); member(U, R2)), K),
  sort(K, R).
```

Using this example graph:

[image]

I get this result:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 4, Runtime Library 1.4.1 (August 20, 2019)

?- plan(21,X).
X = [21-[], 22-[22, 23], 26-[24, 25, 26], 27-[]]
```